# Chaining constructors in an Android (Xamarin) subclass definition

Tags: android, xamarin.android

To minimize duplicate code, I'd like to use constructor-chaining in a custom `GridView`.

The definition below makes calls to the `Init()` method in every constructor:

```
public class GridView2 : GridView        
{
    //public GridView2(IntPtr jRef, JniHandleOwnership jTransfer) : base(jRef, jTransfer) { }        

    public GridView2(Context context) 
        : base(context)
    {
        Init();
    }

    public GridView2(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        Init(); 
    }

    public GridView2(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyleAttr) 
        : base(context, attrs, defaultStyleAttr)
    {
        Init(); 
    }

    public GridView2(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) 
        : base(context, attrs, defaultStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**I would like to avoid this by using constructor-chaining.  However, doing so causes a dependency on the API, and I'm not sure if the convenience is worth it?**

This dependency occurs in the second constructor below

```
public class GridView2 : GridView        
{
    //public GridView2(IntPtr jRef, JniHandleOwnership jTransfer) : base(jRef, jTransfer) { }        

    public GridView2(Context context) 
        : this(context, null) { }
    // dependency API. defStyleAttr could change
    public GridView2(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) 
        : this(context, attrs, Android.Resource.Attribute.GridViewStyle) { }
    public GridView2(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyleAttr) 
        : this(context, attrs, defaultStyleAttr,0) { }
    public GridView2(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) 
        : base(context, attrs, defaultStyleAttr, defStyleRes)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This is due to how Android itself defines this constructor

```
public class GridView extends AbsListView {

    public GridView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    // hardcoded value for defStyleAttr
    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, R.attr.gridViewStyle);
    }

    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        this(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0);
    }

    public GridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);

        // ...
    }   
}
```

Comment: I'm going with the first option, since the chain in the second one is itself creating a dependency for each constructor by preventing the base constructor from being called. If the implementation of any base constructor changes then GridView2 would break...  Even though it is open source, and the stacks run in parallel, mimicking is not the same as consuming (subclassing). Even in raw Java (Dalvik), I don't think I would be mimicking the base classes for the same reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to avoid this by using constructor-chaining. However, doing so causes a dependency on the API, and I'm not sure if the convenience is worth it?

Even if you create `GridView2` instance using `public GridView2(Context context) : base(context)`. The gridview default style is still be applied, because `this(context, attrs, R.attr.gridViewStyle);` is called anyway due to the constructor chain in `GridView` source codes.

So, you are applying the the constructor chain correctly.

Comment: I'm concerned with `GridView2(Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)` b/c of the hardcoded value ***Android.Resource.Attribute.GridViewStyle*** in the **`this`** statement. If the Android implementation changes and uses, say ***R.attr.gridViewStyleNew***, `GridView2` will break.

Comment: I prefer the syntactic succinctness of the chaining in `GridView2`, but If consistently used in all custom views, the dependency grows, setting up for more troubleshooting and code changes should it break. It's a risk I'm not sure is worth taking.

Comment: What do you mean by `Android Implementation changes`? `Android.Resource.Attrubute.GridViewStyle` is a android system resource. It's always there. If you mean the customization of Android system, well, the modification of this name is a wrong-doing, because it will affect all existing apps, which leveraging this system resource.

Comment: There is also the issue of the base class's (GridView) constructor chain. If the implementation of that changes (say the chain is removed so they each have their own implementation instead), then there is another opportunity for code to break.

Comment: Again, it is wrong for system customization to change the implementation of `GridView`, because it will leads to breaking of all existing apps, which leveraging `GridView`. That's why android apps have Android API level restrictions.  If you really want to create an `GridView` that is absolutely independent from android system. You need to create your own `GridView2` Implementation(without deriving from original `GridView`) together with your own style resource in your app.

Comment: I see, this is why Android is backward compatible. Aside from the 5.0 permission changes, an app built for 4.0 should theoretically be able to run on 8.0, correct? I think that is why components are depreciated instead of removed. Not sure how EOL effects this though.